# Textue painting on random places

Tags: texture-painting

I made a model and now I want to do some texture paint on it. The problem is that when I paint a part os the mesh, more texture painting appears on randome places of the mesh. 
Did this happen to you? Does someone know how to fix it.

Hope I can get some help.
Ana. [image]

Comment: It's 99% fault of the bad UV Unwrap. Try to make bigger margins between islands or Unwrap it other way.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try with bigger margins between islands. And still have the option of unwrapping marking seems.